# How achieve variable indirection (refer to a variable whose name is stored in another variable) in tcsh

Tags: shell-script, tcsh, variable-substitution

I'm trying to do the following:

```
set a = kitten
set temp_kitten = purr
echo ${temp_$a}
```

I want the `echo` command to return "purr".

The overall idea is that I have a bunch of variables in an array and a bunch of `temp_variables` in another array and I want to loop through them in a single `foreach` loop for comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `eval`:

```
eval echo \$temp_$a
```

**References**

- [Bash variable indirection](http://www.enricozini.org/2008/tips/bash-indirection/)

Comment: Thanks! I knew it would be something simple like this... The world needs to ban non-bash shells, while they are at it, replacing all word processors and text editors with vim would be nice :D

Is there any way to silence the eval return so I only get the output of the echo?

Comment: @DannyKmack This is not `bash` specific. According to the link I referenced, this should be portable. Also, if this answer solves your problem, please consider accepting it.

Comment: Is there any way to silence the eval return so I only get the output of the echo?

Comment: @DannyKmack Not sure what you mean by the `eval` return. Using `tcsh` on my box and typing `eval echo \$temp_$a` returns `purr` and nothing else.

Comment: Odd, I tried it in a new shell and it didn't happen to me. Thanks again.