# How to retrieve environment variable from string name in KSH

Tags: environment-variables, ksh

I've the following variable :

```
x="envVar"
```

and 'envVar' is the one of my environment variable's name containing a path (of a folder by instance).
So I'd like to do

```
cd $x
```

but it doesn't work. 
How can I do to use x's value as the environment variable ?

I wasn't able to make it work with "eval".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How achieve variable indirection (refer to a variable whose name is stored in another variable) in tcsh](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87941/how-achieve-variable-indirection-refer-to-a-variable-whose-name-is-stored-in-an)

Comment: It's related indeed, however, it doesn't work here.

Comment: `eval cd \$$x`...

Comment: Is ^that what you tried? If so, what happened wrong?

Comment: Ok, I tried a foolish eval cd \$x only (and some other weird stuff). Anyway, thank you very much !

Comment: If you got your answer, you may want to consider deleting this question as it's already one vote away from being put on hold as a duplicate.

Comment: @JosephR. This question is hardly a duplicate. Ksh and csh are too different for that. Even if it was a duplicate, this wouldn't justify deleting the question!

Comment: @Gilles Well, I marked it as duplicate because the same `eval` trick would work in both cases. As for deleting the question, maybe I should ask this on Meta, but what is the advantage of keeping a dupe around?

Comment: @JosephR. Regarding not deleting of duplicates: they're usually useful search fodder, see [Handling duplicate questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/handling-duplicate-questions/), [Do not delete duplicates!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32311), etc. Regarding this question specifically, while there is one answer that works for both, that doesn't make the questions duplicate: questions are only duplicate if any good answer for one also works for the other, which is not the case here (e.g. no [`nameref`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/101208) in tcsh).

Comment: @user1058398 My apologies to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have ksh 93, you can declare `x` to be a reference to a variable name:

```
$ ksh --version
  version         sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01
$ ksh -c '
    envVar=foo
    x=envVar
    nameref x
    echo $x
'
foo
```